# How to analyse a distribution with some given sample moments?

Tags: confidence-interval, skewness, small-sample, moments, kurtosis

Suppose that I have *n* observations, $$X_1,...,X_n$$ with unknown distribution, *n* being small (say, between 6 and 20).
If I know the first four sample moments (average, standard deviation, skewness, kurtosis), there is an infinity of distributions having these four moments, but what can I say about the underlying distribution?

- Can I detect multimodal distribution for instance?
- Are there basic relationships in order to get confidence intervals, without having to calibrate a distribution on these four moments?

Comment: Those moments are connected by inequalities. This is called the [Hamburger moment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_moment_problem).

Comment: If you observe those $n$ observations, you know every sample moment and not only the first four moments.

Comment: Thank you Xi'an. I will look at your suggestion. Just to clarify, I don't know the n observations, but I only know the first four moments.

Comment: In general you cannot tell from the first four moments whether you have unimodality, multimodality or whatever else (with only a few possible exceptions -- e.g. that the variance is 0 or the kurtosis attains its minimum possible value).

e.g. if the kurtosis is say 3 you could have any number of modes, unless the squared skewness strictly attains the bound imposed by kurtosis.